# How to impelement one class of class library project into another class of another class library project in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nopcommerce

I have created a store in `nopcommerce` and now I want to add my own plugin in that store.

For that, 
I have created one class library project and in that I have created one class in which I have to implement `IPlugin` Interface which resides in another class of another class library project.

Now, I can't access that class in my solution.

So what should I do for implementing it in my class library?

Comment: Please don't indent text by four spaces unless it's code or formatted text (e.g. tables) that you want displayed like code. Indenting by four spaces causes the text to be displayed pre-formatted and with syntax highlighting turned on.

Comment: I think better you Import that library in your project and try to access it namespace I think it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remember that class should be public,so you can access outside of the project
second ,build project
third,add reference to another project and .DLL file